# jQuery autocomplete using source option with php returning all values

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to use the jQuery autocomplete function to search through a list of activities.  The user should enter a few letters of an activity in the text box, such as 'ai' and the autocomplete should have a list of activities containing these letters pop up below, such as 'aikido', 'model aircraft', etc...  The list of activities is stored in a mysql database on the server and I'm calling a php script to get the list of activities and pass it to the jQuery autocomplete function.  For some strange reason, however, the autocomplete is currently listing all activities in the drop-down box below whether they contain the text the user has entered or not.

Here is my HTML:

```
<label for="activity">Select Activity:</label>
<input id="activity">
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
$( "#activity" ).autocomplete({
    source: "php/getActivities.php"
});
```

Here is my php file:

```
<?php // CreateAdForm.php

// Connect to database
include_once 'dbConnect.php';

$activities = array();

$query = "SELECT activity FROM activities WHERE listed=true";
$resource = mysql_query($query);

// Push all these activities onto the array
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resource)) {

    array_push($activities, $row[0]);

} // end of loop through activities

// Return the activities
echo json_encode($activities);


?>
```

I think the problem is with the 'echo json_encode($activities);' line in the php file.  I think I should be echo the JSON data in a different format.  I'm just not too sure what format.

Thanks for any help,

Tom

Comment: use `header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add a condition in your SQL to filter the results by the search term. Try doing this in your PHP script:

```
<?php // CreateAdForm.php

// Connect to database
include_once 'dbConnect.php';

// Search term
$term = $_GET['term']; /////

$activities = array();

$query = "SELECT activity FROM activities WHERE listed=true AND activity LIKE '%" . $term . "%'";
$resource = mysql_query($query);

// Push all these activities onto the array
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resource)) {

    array_push($activities, $row[0]);

} // end of loop through activities

// Return the activities
echo json_encode($activities);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the minLength option to your autocomplete

```
$( "#activity" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,    
    source: "php/getActivities.php"
});
```

Comment: This still produces the same behaviour - it lists all activities in the database.  It's just that now the user must enter two characters before it does it.